# C++ Access Typename from Templated Class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to access a type from a templated class. I created a wrapper for an RTOS to make my Code RTOS nondependend

```
class CRTOS_Wrapper
{
public:

  ///the desired class ID
  using Task_ID* = void*;

  /**
   * Returns the handle to the current thread
   * @return Handle to the current thread
   */
  static const Task_ID * OS_Get_Thread_ID();
}
```

each RTOS wrapper looks exactly the same.

another working class receives the desired wrapper as a template parameter

```
template<typename RTOS_Wrapper_T>
  class CWorker
{
///this does not work
      void Do_Something(RTOS_Wrapper_T::Task_ID task);
private:
      RTOS_Wrapper_T rtos_wrapper_instance;
}
```

The compiler cannot resolve Task_ID. Can i somehow access the Task ID or is it not possible?

Thx for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried using `(typename RTOS_Wrapper_T::Task_ID task)`?

Comment: The first `*` in `using Task_ID* = void*;` looks suspicious. Are you sure about that one?

Comment: thx the typename was missing :)